# Construct proofs for the following sequents, using only primitive inference rules

Tags: propositional-calculus

1.(P & R) → S,  S ↔ T,  ─T  ├  R → ─P

2. P v Q,   P → (T → S),  P → T,  S ↔ Q  ├  S

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are "primitive" inference rules ?

Comment: For 2), use [Disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination).

Comment: For 1), use [Conditional proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof) and [Negation introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_introduction).